# WordPress Plugin and Usage

Tags: wordpress

I installed a plugin for wordpress and activated it.

then I post a few of them under this Custom Post Types.

However, how do you view a list view of them (the ones I just posted)?

right now, I can only view a single post at a time.   I also see inside the file directory, there a file called archive-xxx.php. I think that's used for displaying a archive or list of all this custom post types.  But how do I make sure of it?

Download and try it see if you can create a few posts and display them
http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/creating-client-testimonials-with-custom-post-types/

Comment: What is the name of the plugin your using? What are you trying to do? Your question is very confusing and unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The post type will have a [page-template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) to show the post. You need to create a page with that page template. All the posts in that "Custom Post Type" will appear in that page.

You can refer to [this](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/08/complete-guide-custom-post-types/) or [this](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/a-guide-to-wordpress-custom-post-types-creation-display-and-meta-boxes/) article for a better tutorial on custom post types.

Comment: no, I don't see the page atrribute on the right hand side where you can select the template.

Comment: can you give some details about your plugin, and a link to the plugin maybe?

Comment: You can try it. http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/creating-client-testimonials-with-custom-post-types/       I specifically put template name: in comment section of the archive-testimonials.php  but no page attribute show when creating a new post.